# Database Deployment issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, deployment, webforms

I'm having a hard time deploying my website.
I got through some errors and they got resolved and I successfully published my website but when I try to open any page it gives me 404 or 500 Error

My host provider told me that if this page is using a database and it's not deployed then this is might be the problem
so I tried to deploy my database and I get the connectionString error.

The problem is that I'm not storing my connectionString in the web.config
It's stored in a property in my base DAL class and it's used by all the DAL classes
so I updated it but I get the same error

I dont know what's wrong, should I include the connectionString in the web.config ?

**N.B** When I build the package and I try to set the active mode to 'release' it returns the setting to 'debug'!

Comment: Try to connect to your remote database with your website in vs debugger mode, and see what the exception is.

Comment: Is the database hosted somewhere that can be reached from your hosting provider?

Comment: @mservidio .. I tried to access my database from VS2010 and it was successful and I didn't face any problems, I ran quiries and stuff

Comment: @alun .. I'm not sure I understand your question, It's hosted on my local machine in the SqlExpress. and they were able to access and publish my presentation layer I think they can also access the database. I'm sorry, can you clarify what exactly do you want to know ?

Comment: Unless you are setting specific response headers or your hosting provider has some weird configuration a 404 means you are not even hitting your page, and a 500 usually means that IIS cannot parse your web.config file.

Comment: @Luis .. why wouldn't the IIS parse my web.config .. and is there is any specific kind of information I need to specify any information in my web.config before I publish it ?

Comment: A 500 is an internal server error that can be anything, including but not limited to an erroneous web.config.

Comment: @DonAndre .. how can I debug this to know exactly what's wrong ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm sorry but all the answers advised me that I need to place the 'ConnectionString' in 'Web.config' but actually the whole problem was solved when I added my application to a virtual directory and I didn't need to change my DAL layer or add anything to the web.config

Of course I learned from your answers and I appreciate it but no I don't need to add anything in my web.config If I decided to have this design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> "should I include the connectionString in the web.config ?"

Yes, your connection string should be defined in the `<connectionStrings>` section of the web.config for precisely this reason - so that you can easily change the setting to point to a different database environment when deploying your application to a different environment, without needing to recompile your code.

Comment: Ok, but I already defined in my base DAL class a connectionString and I updated it to be set to my new database connectionString. and when I publish it already rebuilds my classes and create a new DLLs, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

IIS recognizes your connection strings in the config file. I've seen it exposing them through the IIS management console when viewing a certain application. I had a similar problem once and it turned out it was an authentication issue. Applications on IIS run in a certain pool and under a certain user. If you specified to use windows authentication (integrated security) in your connection string then this user must have rights to access the database. If the user that runs the application doesn't have the necessary rights to connect to the database you should specify the username and password explicitly in the connection string.

In any case you can turn on `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` in your web.config and get a little bit more information on why your service is failing like so ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942778.aspx)):

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior>
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: I think this is great but I have a shared hosting account so I need to specify a user and pass and I already declared it in my connectionString. maybe the problem is about my quiries .. for example my sql statement goes like this "SELECT * FROM Table1 not user.Table1 .. do I have to change my whole DAL to include the db user ? .. btw I declared my connectionString in a class in order to secure it from anyone who uses my application to modify it so I could be the only one who can make this application work, so is this is wrong ?

Comment: You can't really "secure" the connection string. Certainly you can prevent people from modifying it, but it's a bit questionable why you want to do that. The only way to secure this information is to remove it entirely and have the user or the end user provide it. Of course in an application that runs on IIS there's no way, but to include it. However, if you include it in the config you can still only do so at IIS locally and you don't have to ship this string to other places.

Comment: Regarding your queries, I don't think this should really be an issue. If at all then you would need to qualify it with the scheme name (dbo is the default name). And also you have to consider that the queries do work locally. Have you already tried to get the exact exception details? I think for debugging you should really turn this on temporarily, otherwise you'll just be guessing.

Comment: DonAndre I agree with you but I don't know in which sections should I add this in my web.config ? and should I put it in the main web.config or the release one ?

Comment: I have my local debug connection string in the main config and in the release I use an xdt:Transform to replace it. Connection strings go into the [configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx) section. Including the exceptions goes into configuration > system.servicemodel > behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your DAL is a class library, I would store the connection string in app.config. That way, you can easily change the connection string without having to put the connection string in every web application that uses the library.

Comment: Yes it's a class library. I have a base class that all my DAL classes inherit from. in the base class I have the property ConnectionString which is set in the development stage and after i'm done it's protected in the DLL and any class who inherit from this base class can use the property ConnectionString very easily. the only layer that need to know about my database and it's connectionString is the DAL .. so my web application will never need to know what's the connectionString is .. I've tried to give you more details about my design, Hope you could help

Comment: Your design will be more flexible if you have the `ConnectionString` property pull the connection string from the app.config of the library. If you're concerned about security, just encrypt the connection string section after deployment.

Comment: Ok and if I did that, I don't need any connectionStrings in the web.config ? .. and btw where can I find app.config ?

Comment: That's correct. You won't need to store your connection strings in the web.config. If the class library doesn't contain an app.config file, just add one by going to `Add > New Item > Application Configuration File`

Answer (score 1):

"The problem is that I'm not storing my connectionString in the web.config It's stored in a property in my base DAL class and it's used by all the DAL classes so I updated it but I get the same error"

Yes, hard coding connection strings is a major problem. To answer your next question "should I include the connectionString in the web.config?", the answer is YES.

As for proper deployment of a database, you can look at [this blog entry](http://gregorybeamer.wordpress.com/2008/06/07/deploying-a-local-database-to-your-isp-sql-server-database-publishing-wizard/) I created in 2008.

Comment: Ok but the connectionString will be located in the web application project and my DAL in a seperate class library .. how will I be able to access it from my DAL ?

Comment: If you can't magically get the connection string from the config, how would you think you get it to a DAL class? The mechanism to get it there is simple: pass it in as a parameter to the method called to get your data. I assume, since you have it hard coded, you already have the mechanism for setting the connection string.

Comment: hmm so everytime I connect to the database I should pass the ConnectionString ? .. there's noway to store it in the web.config to avoide the problems of hard coding the connectionString and can still access the web.config connection strings from my DAL Class Library ?

Comment: You can do that, but separation of concerns dictates that the separate library is fed its answers rather than pulling from config. If you don't you tightly couple your DAL to the UI config. I have seen a kludge someone created to config a library, but why use a lot of reflection when you don't have to.

Comment: Gregory! You're making me confused. so how can stay away from coupling my application and can still publish my web solution to work online :S ?

Comment: Coupling details a requirement that a particular library requires a particular UI type and/or a particular database type. Just because you state the connection string has to be fed to your DAL does not couple it to a web application, as a Silverlight application can do the same. And it does not couple you to config. If your DAL pulls directly from the config, then it is coupled to a configuration file. Not a serious issue, from some perspectives, as .NET is about config files. But, something else may come in the future, which is why it is wise not to couple.