# After copying my asp.net website I get 500 and 404 errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, webforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Database Deployment issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574499/database-deployment-issues)

I followed the steps in this video:

http://www.asp.net/iis/videos/developing-and-deploying-in-a-shared-hosting

I just open my website on VS2010. then use the copy tool and I create a new directory and copy my web application into this new dir. the copy is done successfully but when I try to access it I get 500 for the main page which contain only some static menus and when I try to access any of my other pages it gives me a 404 error!

I tried to add some sections to my web.config to handle the errors and show me what's exactly wrong as advised before but It won't give me any details! .. also when I try to remotely access my IIS I can only see the folder of my application but I can't see any files! and the icon for my application is a normal folder, I've seen some screenshots of an IIS of a deployed website and the folder icon is converted to an application icon.

I've also tried to click on my application in IIS a right click > Deploy > Convert To Application. but it generates "An Error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer. the server experienced an issue processing the request"!

I've been trying to deploy my website for 3 days and posted three questions with no results! :S

**Problem Solved**

I've tried to speak to my provider again today and an agent advised me that I need to have my application on a virtual path to deploy it as an application. and it worked.
But I marked Chris's answer as the correct one not because it's the only answer but has really stated some good points and I really appreciate his help.
Thank you so much guys :)

Comment: It actually looks like you've gotten 5 answers to your previous two questions (as opposed to "no results").

Comment: non of them worked! .. I mean I appreciate it but I'm still in the same place!

Comment: and I just want to add that I was concerned about the database deployment but then I realized that even if I excluded the database deployment and tried to run my static pages. I'm still getting an error. so I think I should focus on how to deploy the website itself then I can think about the database

Comment: Could it be that your relative paths are no longer valid? Did you deploy this application to a virtual directory or something?

Comment: @JamesJohnson .. This is my first time to deploy a web application so how do I know if I deployed it to a virtual directory ? .. and btw I'm not sure if it's against rules to put my url here to see the errors!

Comment: @IKashef: Generally speaking, the main reason to not publish the URL to your site is a security one.  However, there are no rules against doing so if it aids in figuring out the problem.

Comment: @IKashef: I think it's okay if you revise your question and include a link to the site. I've seen many people do it, and I don't recall seeing any questions closed on account of it, so I'm assuming that it's okay.

Comment: I think if you have just used the file copy, then in inetmgr you have to convert the web site to an application.

Comment: I tried to copy the website then from IIS I right clicked it > Deply > Convert To Application and I got an error "An Error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer. the server experienced an issue processing the request". and I tried to use the publish tool and it still won't work

Comment: @0A0D .. This is also my question and I just stated the same possible causes as they might be connected. But this question is about the deployment of the website disregarding the db part. and anyway I found the solution to my error and I will update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. 404 means file not found. 404's won't be caught by the .net runtime, unless it's for a file with a regular .net extension like .aspx.  500 is an internal server error.

Things I would investigate

1. Can you deploy just a regular HTML file and load it?
   if this works, move to #2.  If not then either you aren't pointed to the right machine or you aren't deploying your files to the correct location.
2. Can you deploy a very simple (nearly blank and self contained) .aspx file and load it?  If this works, then .Net is installed.  If not, then you need to figure that out.
3. Can you look at the file system to see if anything is actually there?  If you aren't seeing it, then it didn't get deployed.
4. Is the appropriate version of the .Net framework installed on the remote computer?
   Basically, if your app is a .Net 4.0 app, then you need the 4.0 framework installed on the machine.
5. Is the app pool correctly configured for the correct .net framework version?
   Regardless of whether the correct version of the .net framework is installed, you still have to configure the website to use the right version of the .net framework.

Some helpful hints.  Don't deploy to c:\inetpub\wwwroot.  wwwroot is a directory for the default IIS website and is usually not configured correctly.  Just create another directory like c:\inetpub\myapp and deploy there.  Also, make sure you disable the default website in IIS and create a new site (not a virtual directory) and point it to the correct location.

I suspect that either you aren't deploying to the correct location and/or your iis settings are bad.

Somewhere along the way on the above you ought to figure it out.

Comment: Crhis .. do I just go to my File Manager and create an Html document or what method do you suggest I should use to guide me to the required results ?

Comment: @IKashef: Yeah, just create a simple .html doc, doesn't even have to be formatted correctly, "publish" that to your server and see if you can access it.

Comment: Ok so for the first step I created an html document with my notepad and uploaded it using an FTP client and I tried to open and it successfully open .. is it okay because I'm afraid that you mean something specific by "publish" !?

Comment: Now I've tried to Publish an empty asp.net application but I get the same 500 thing! .. I tried to just copy the files via FTP but I get the same error. also tried to copy just WebFrom1.aspx, WebFrom1.cs, WebFrom1.designer but I still get the same error .. so does this mean that that asp.net is not installed or It's not a must ?

Comment: @IKashef: It sure sounds like either the .net framework isn't installed or the app pool isn't configured correctly.

Comment: the problem is that the default page that I've got when I purchased my shared hosting acount is an .aspx page and it's working :S

Comment: Well, how can I configure the application pool because I think I got an error mentioning something about it in the beginning .. and btw as I've told you the IIS don't see my application, it just see it as a folder! .. if I clicked "View Applications" I won't see any!

Comment: "Also, make sure you disable the default website in IIS and create a new site (not a virtual directory) and point it to the correct location." I don't get what you mean by the default website and how can I disable it and point it ?